# Node Js data split and appended incorrectly

Tags: html, node.js

I have a text file with several rows with numbers like this for example:

```
2;1;80;3.4;5%;12%;30%;43%;10%;
2;2;20;4;0%;9%;22%;30%;39%;
2;3;80;4;0%;9%;22%;30%;39%;
2;4;20;3.4;5%;12%;30%;43%;10%;
2;5;80;3.7;3%;7%;30%;37%;23%;
2;6;20;3.7;3%;7%;30%;37%;23%;
```

What I try to do is append at the beginning the user ID (which user inputs) and to append at the end of every row what user inputs from select tags (it's just one number-rank) and also the initial time and end time when the user submits the form. All of this is appended properly except the fact that I get this row split (except on the last row) like this:

```
11;2;1;80;4;2%;5%;38%;40%;15%;
2;2018-4-26;13:38:12;2018-4-26;13:38:25
11;2;2;20;4;0%;20%;5%;35%;40%;
1;2018-4-26;13:38:12;2018-4-26;13:38:25
11;2;3;80;4;0%;2%;37%;27%;35%;
5;2018-4-26;13:38:12;2018-4-26;13:38:25
11;2;4;20;4;0%;15%;20%;20%;45%;
6;2018-4-26;13:38:12;2018-4-26;13:38:25
11;2;5;80;3.6;5%;0%;25%;70%;0%;
3;2018-4-26;13:38:12;2018-4-26;13:38:25
11;2;6;20;3.6;5%;10%;25%;35%;25%;4;2018-4-26;13:38:12;2018-4-26;13:38:25
```

My app.js:

```
app.post('/submit', function(req, res){

    const choices = [ req.body.rank1, req.body.rank2, req.body.rank3, req.body.rank4, req.body.rank5, req.body.rank6];
    var id = fs.readFileSync('temporary/userID.txt', 'utf8');
    var timeSTART = fs.readFileSync('temporary/timeSTART1.txt', 'utf8');

    var timeEND = req.body.created_at = new Date().toLocaleString('it-IT', {hour12: false, timezone: 'Europe/Rome'}).replace(/ /, ';');
    fs.appendFileSync('temporary/timeEND1.txt', timeEND + ';' , 'utf8');

    var ranks = fs.readFile('public/data/data1.txt','utf-8',(err, file) => fs.appendFileSync(
                        'output.txt',file.split('\n').map( (line) =>
                        id + line+ choices.shift() + ';' +timeSTART + timeEND).join('\n'),(err) => {}
                            ));
    fs.appendFileSync('output.txt', '\n\n' , 'utf8');

  res.sendfile('main2.html');
});
```

I would like the output to look as the last row of the output looks but instead I have this split in the middle of the other rows. Does somebody see an error? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `join`, you don't need it.

You also don't need an empty error function.

So just change this:

```
var ranks = fs.readFile('public/data/data1.txt','utf-8',(err, file) => fs.appendFileSync(
                    'output.txt',file.split('\n').map( (line) =>
                    id + line+ choices.shift() + ';' +timeSTART + timeEND).join('\n'),(err) => {}
                        ));
```

to this:

```
var ranks = fs.readFile('public/data/data1.txt','utf-8',(err, file) => fs.appendFileSync(
                    'output.txt',file.split('\n').map( (line) =>
                    id + line+ choices.shift() + ';' +timeSTART + timeEND)
                        ));
```

Play around this bug here: https://repl.it/@rafaelcastrocouto/BriskAchingExecutables